# How to change device wallpaper with react native (in 2021)

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, wallpaper, android-wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I am trying to build an app which can change the wallpaper.. I tried using react-native-manage-wallpaper to do the same; but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.WallPaperManager.setWallpaper')
```

I have explained this problem here in detail:
[I am getting an error while using manage-wallpaper library in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810850/i-am-getting-an-error-while-using-manage-wallpaper-library-in-react-native)

I have also tried solutions described [here](https://github.com/liuhong1happy/react-native-wallpaper-manager/issues/4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740712/how-to-add-set-as-wallpaper-option-in-react-native-app)

But I haven't yet got any useful solution anywhere...Is there a way to do the same task using any other library?

Comment: most likely that module is not installed properly